# ElasticSearch[5.5] Aggs Range filter on string datatype

Tags: elasticsearch, search, aggregate, searchfiltercollection

**RAM** field in Mobile specifications has lots of data which i need to apply some kind of Range filter on strings . I have formatted bucket into key value pair RAM and Doc count

```
 "RAM": {
            "1": 7,
            "32": 1,
            "32 MB": 490,
            "1 GB": 426,
            "2 GB": 361,
            "3 GB": 269,
            "4 GB": 143,
            "512 MB": 136,
            "256 MB": 87,
            "10 MB": 61,
            "64 MB": 47,
            "1 MB": 45,
            "128 MB": 41,
            "56 MB": 27,
            "1.5 GB": 23,
            "16 MB": 12,
            "35 MB": 12,
            "4 MB": 11,
            "0.032 MB": 10,
            "100 MB": 7,
            "3 MB": 7,
            "2 MB": 6,
            "768 MB": 6,
            "40 MB": 4,
            "30 MB": 3,
            "6 GB": 3,
            "20 MB": 2,
            "46 MB": 2,
            "500 MB": 2,
            "60 MB": 2,
            "120 MB": 1,
            "131 MB": 1,
            "138 MB": 1,
            "153 MB": 1,
            "200 MB": 1,
            "24 MB": 1,
            "250 MB": 1,
            "260 MB": 1,
            "50 MB": 1,
            "55 MB": 1,
            "65 MB": 1,
            "8 GB": 1
        }
```

How to convert the above one to something like below

```
 128 MB and Below
     1 GB
     2 GB
     3 GB
     4 GB
     6 GB and Above
```

One possible solution would be index the value of RAM as numeric datatype and apply range filter on the field. But how to differentiate 1 Mb and 1 GB .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by convert all that in the lowest unit and removed the conversion unit.

please check here

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-5-5-aggs-range-filter-on-string-datatype/106400/3